# Create a document in Firestore that includes a reference to an existing document in another collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to post new documents to a collection which contain references to existing documents.

Here is my code:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://DBURL.firebaseio.com'
});

var db = admin.firestore();

db.collection('myFunCollection').add({
  someBool: false,
  someNumber: 13.2,
  video: 'videos/Izdm35CsW6kqv2UxZEX0',
  user: 'users/pb7La4kzEaBow4iWvmxZ'
});
```

`video` and `user` reference existing documents in other collections, but when I run this code, the fields are stored as strings rather than references. [The documentation notably does not describe how to do this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types).

How can I post these values as references?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out – by using "db.doc('{path}')"

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://DBURL.firebaseio.com'
});

var db = admin.firestore(); 

db.collection('myFunCollection').add({
  someBool: false,
  someNumber: 13.2,
  video: db.doc('videos/Izdm35CsW6kqv2UxZEX0'),
  user: db.doc('users/pb7La4kzEaBow4iWvmxZ')
});
```